# Simple solution to create tree-like structure in html

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio

I am trying to create a tree-like structure for a webpage. In my case a user has a set of projects, each project has a set of tasks, tasks can have sub-tasks, and sub-tasks can have their own sub-tasks. So, basically I am looking for an elegant solution to display the tree-like structure using html elements in an aesthetically pleasing manor. Any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a good place to start would be to make some psudo-code. most people on this website wont give you an entire solution. i have almost no knowledge of html but in all other programming languages the first place to start would be psudo code. also this sounds like you need to make some objects and structure your code around them.

Comment: awesome reply, would've been more appreciated as a comment though

Comment: I'm not exactly looking for an answer just for someone to point me in the right direction. I have built these objects using C# as a programming language. Just my front-end is html and that is where my strengths are weak.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave this as a comment but I'm lacking a couple of rep points. You may want to focus more on the javascript part of building the tree. The HTML is the easy part. Do some searching on jQuery treeview control and see what you come back with. Here's an example:

http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'm new with building a webpage but very familiar with programming in the c family and java. Thanks.

Comment: Head over to http://www.w3schools.com/. Tons of quick easy tutorials that will have you up and running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link -

[here](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu)

Very good explanation. You can customize according to your need.